Alder Lake N - UEFI GPIO Register Defaults/Initialisation
I purchased an obscure NAS only sold to the Chinese domestic market (Zspace Z4Pro) with a view to using another OS on it since it was intel based (i3-N305)
For reasons unknown the power to the drive bays is individually controlled with an npn + mosfet driven by a GPIO.
The default state is off and then toggled from within the stock OS - possibly as a rudimentary measure to prevent using another OS or possibly (given the SMBIOS is full of "Default Strings") they just didn't know what they were doing.
GPIOs



gpio_name
gpio_number
pad_name
DW0
DW1
DW2




sata0_power_gpio
681
GPPC_B_17
0x04000201
0x00000029
0x00000100


sata1_power_gpio
680
GPPC_B_16
0x04000201
0x00000028
0x00000100


sata2_power_gpio
672
GPPC_B_8
0x04000201
0x00000020
0x00000100


sata3_power_gpio
671
GPPC_B_7
0x04000201
0x0000001f
0x00000100



DW0 Register (0x04000201)



Bit Range
Field Name
Description
Value




31-30
PADRSTCFG
Pad Reset Config
0x0 (Powergood)


29-29
RXPADSTSEL
RX Pad State Select
0x0 (Raw RX pad state directly from CFIO RX buffer)


28-28
RXRAW1
RX Raw Override to '1'
0x0 (No Override)


27-27
NAF_VWE
Native Function Virtual Wire Message Enable
0x0 (Disable pad input event sampling and VW message generation.)


26-25
RXEVCFG
RX Level/Edge Configuration
0x2 (Disable)


24-24
PREGFRXSEL
Pre Glitch Filter Stage RX Pad State Select
0x0 (Select synchronized, non filtered RX pad state)


23-23
RXINV
RX Invert
0x0 (No inversion)


22-21
RXTXENCFG
RX/TX Enable Config
0x0 (Function defined in Pad Mode controls TX and RX Enables)


20-20
GPIROUTIOXAPIC
GPIO Input Route IOxAPIC
0x0 (Routing does not cause peripheral IRQ)


19-19
GPIROUTSCI
GPIO Input Route SCI
0x0 (Routing does not cause SCI)


18-18
GPIROUTSMI
GPIO Input Route SMI
0x0 (Routing does not cause SMI)


17-17
GPIROUTNMI
GPIO Input Route NMI
0x0 (Routing does not cause NMI)


16-13
RESERVED
Reserved
0x0


12-10
PMODE
Pad Mode
0x0 (GPIO controls the Pad)


9-9
GPIORXDIS
GPIO RX Disable
0x1 (Disable the input buffer of the pad)


8-8
GPIOTXDIS
GPIO TX Disable
0x0 (Enable the output buffer (active low enable) of the pad)


7-2
RESERVED
Reserved
0x0


1-1
GPIORXSTATE
GPIO RX State
0x0 (Current internal RX pad state is 0)


0-0
GPIOTXSTATE
GPIO TX State
0x1 (Drive a level '1' to the TX output pad)



I can power the bays up within an OS just by setting GPIO manually:
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio681/value

I'd like to understand where the registers for these pads are initialised.
Additionally I'm a little confused as if I set the gpio within linux (i.e power the drives up), on reboot the power is dropped immediately (not so good for the disks of course)
But if my understanding of power states and PADRSTCFG is correct, this shouldn't happen?
Plan Z is hardware approach.

Normally BIOS will initialization GPIOs, so when reboot, the BIOS will re-initialization again
